# JavaScript element src change

Tags: javascript, html

So I have two images, "safety-pin-green" and "safety-pin-blue" and I want to change the image elements source depending on which the contents of the source when called, this will be for mouse over and mouse out. 
Here's the JavaScript:

```
function changeImage(id) {
var src = document.getElementById(id).src;  
    if (src.search("green") != 0) {
        src = src.replace("green", "blue");
    } else {
        src = src.replace("blue", "green");
    }
    document.getElementById(id).src = src;
}
```

and the HTML tag i'm using:

```
<img id="safety-pin" src="../images/safety-pin-green.jpg" alt="Safety pin"
    onmouseover="changeImage(id)" onmouseout="changeImage(id)"></img>
```

The code almost works, the images go blue, but they don't return to the green image when the mouse leaves the image, any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MDN documentation of [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search),

> Return value
>
> The index of the first match between the regular expression and the given string; if not found, -1.

Replace

```
src.search("green") != 0
```

with

```
src.search("green") !== -1
```

Comment: I see, I wasn't to sure how the search feature works. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :) a simple '>' solves my problem.

```
if (src.search("green") > 0) {
    src = src.replace("green", "blue");
}...
```